# Windows Powershell & Managing NLB CLusters

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, nlb

I am in the process of developing scripts to allow automated management of Clustered servers, and as part of that I have a requirement to be able to stop and start cluster nodes from a Powershell script.

The code I am using for this is as follows:

```
Import-Module NetworkLoadBalancingClusters

Stop-NlbClusterNode [[-HostName] <string>] [-InterfaceName <string>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

But on running this script on 3 different environments (Windows 7/Windows Server 2003/Windows Server 2008 R2) all with Powershell v2, I get the following error:

> ```
>  Get-NlbCluster : This method is not implemented in any class 
>  At line:6 char:15
>  + Get-NlbCluster <<<<  -HostName "SERVER1" -InterfaceName "10.172.1.180"
>  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-NlbCluster], ManagementException
>  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.ManagementException,Microsoft.NetworkLoadBalancingClusters.PowerShell.GetNlbCluster.
> ```

Does anyone know what I have done wrong here which is causing this error?

Thanks In Advance,

Stuart

Answer (score 0):

This only works on Windows Server 2008 R2 and you have to install the Network Load Balancing feature.